# Python - file contents to nested list

Tags: python, file, list, newline, tabs

I have a file in tab delimited format with trailing newline characters, e.g.,

```
123   abc
456   def
789   ghi
```

I wish to write function to convert the contents of the file into a nested list. To date I have tried:

```
def ls_platform_ann():
    keyword = []
    for line in open( "file", "r" ).readlines():
        for value in line.split():
            keyword.append(value)
```

and

```
def nested_list_input():
    nested_list = []
    for line in open("file", "r").readlines():
        for entry in line.strip().split():
            nested_list.append(entry)
            print nested_list
```

.

The former creates a nested list but includes \n and \t characters. The latter does not make a nested list but rather lots of equivalent lists without \n and \t characters.

Anyone help?

Regards,
S ;-)

Comment: you don't need `.readlines()` when iterating over text file. Also your `ls_platform_ann` **does not** create nested list. Or you're not showing us all relevant code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option that doesn't involve the [csv](http://file///opt/local/share/doc/python26-doc/library/csv.html) module is:

```
data = [[item.strip() for item in line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')] for line in open('input.txt')]
```

As a multiple line statement it would look like this:

```
data = []
for line in open('input.txt'):
    items = line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')   # strip new-line characters and split on column delimiter
    items = [item.strip() for item in items]  # strip extra whitespace off data items
    data.append(items)
```

Answer (score 8):

You want the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.

```
import csv

source = "123\tabc\n456\tdef\n789\tghi"
lines = source.split("\n")

reader = csv.reader(lines, delimiter='\t')

print [word for word in [row for row in reader]]
```

Output:

```
[['123', 'abc'], ['456', 'def'], ['789', 'ghi']]
```

In the code above Ive put the content of the file right in there for easy testing. If youre reading from a file from disk you can do this as well (which might be considered cleaner):

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("source.csv"), delimiter='\t')

print [word for word in [row for row in reader]]
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, have a look at the [csv](http://file:///opt/local/share/doc/python26-doc/library/csv.html) module, it should handle the whitespace for you. You may also want to call `strip()` on value/entry.